# Continuations in python

Tags: python

is there any equivalent construct for continuations in python. I have been reading about continuations and am just being curious and want to know as there is nothing about that in the docs.

Comment: Are you asking if Python has a call/cc mechanism?  Any language with first-class functions supports continuations.

Comment: http://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/~duchier/python/continuations.html

Comment: my question is more in the line of if continuations are supported in python then how can they be expressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is more in the line of if continuations are supported in python then how can they be expressed?

They are expressed the same way in Python as in any other language without [call/cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation): by passing a function as the continuation argument to another function.  Consider the *very* silly example of a continuation that is applied to the sum of two numbers.  In ML, you might write

```
fun plus(x, y, k) = k(x + y)

plus(2, 4, print o Int.toString)
```

which prints 6.

but in Python you might write

```
def plus(x, y, k):
    return k(x + y)

plus(2, 4, lambda n: print '%d' % n)
```

which also prints 6.

Comment: Can this actually be used as continuations? Wouldn't you run in to stack overflows if you made long chains of this?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan My mistake.  Fixed.

Comment: @AHM Yes and yes.  In both languages, `plus` takes a continuation `k`.  Also, Python doesn't attempt to optimize the stack by replacing stack frames on continuation calls, so any CPS code in Python could blow the stack with a sufficiently long chain.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin isn't continuations supposed to work like goto, so that you could use them to construct circular chains if you wanted? Like the classic ping/pong example. The python solution here is basically just passing callbacks to functions, and that would result in stack overflow. Not really continuations, is it?

Comment: @AHM As I say in the answer, it's a very silly example.  However, this really *is* continuation-passing, because `plus` is calling the continuation `k` with the result of some (in this case very simple) computation.  Python doesn't optimize tail calls, so a long enough chain of continuations *will* blow the stack, no matter the application.

Comment: This is a simple method call with a function argument. This does not do what a continuation does. -1

Comment: This is *not* a continuation. Execution of a continuation can be suspended and resumed by the language. `plus` cannot. Its just a function value, not a continuation.

Comment: Python functions are not lexical - they don't capture state when defined. `x = 3; def myclosure(): return x + 1; myclosure() ## returns 4; x = 4; myclosure() ## returns 5 - # this is not a closure!!` Thus your lambda nor function definition can't capture the state - what is the main task of a continuation!